# How to style child components in react styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to style the child component of a styled-component, but it sends the css to the parent instead of the child/ This is my code,

```
export const Card = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  ${props => props.horizontal && `
  ${CardImage}{
     max-height: 60%;
     overflow: hidden;
  }`}
`
export const CardImage = styled.div`
    position: relative;
`
```

EDIT: When I add a condition before rendering that's when it doesn't work

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're almost there, you're just missing a `$` in your code and you'll need to move the CardImage above the Card component:

```
export const CardImage = styled.div`
    position: relative;
`

export const Card = styled.div`
    position: relative;
    ${CardImage}{
        max-height: 60%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
`
```

Edit (04/04/2018):

If you want to add a condition around a whole block like you have, you need to import the `css` function from styled components and use that:

```
import styled, {css} from "styled-components";

export const CardImage = styled.div`
    position: relative;
`

export const Card = styled.div`
    position: relative;

    ${props => props.horizontal && css` // - Notice the css` here.
        ${CardImage}{
            max-height: 60%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    `}
`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I try to add a condition before styling it doesn't work. Look at the edit

Comment: @Marvin You need to declare `CardImage` before `Card` like in my example, I've also updated my example for your new condition

Comment: @CubedEye what if you wanted to style CardImage from Card, using the props that you pass to CardImage? How could you access the props that CardImage is receiving when instantiated inside that Card container?

Comment: @CubedEye: What if I want to pass children to `CardImage`? Doing `<CardImage>Some Text</CardImage>` does not work. I get error "No overload matches this call" when using this pattern in TypeScript with React.

Answer (score 0):

```
const StyledCard = styled.div`
   //parent styles goes here
`;
const StyledImage = styled.img`
   //image styles
`;

class CardImage extends Component {
   render() {
     return <StyledImage/>
}

export default class Card extends Component {
  render() {
    return <StyledCard>
               <CardImage/>
           </StyledCard>
  }
}
```

Should it work for you?

Comment: I don't want to join the card and card image into the same component. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You can separate them into different components as well. I've edited my answer - is that what you meant?